# Unable to create column of BINARY data type in MySql. It's showing "Invalid Datatype"/"missing right parenthesis" error

Tags: mysql

Unable to create column of BINARY/VARBINARY data type in MySql.

**CREATE TABLE temp_pos_bitmap(privilege_bitmap NUMBER,　dec_bin BINARY);**

Getting the below SQL error while trying to execute the above mentioned create table with binary data type,

SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"

**CREATE TABLE temp_pos_bitmap(privilege_bitmap NUMBER,　dec_bin BINARY(64));**

Getting the below SQL error while trying to execute the above mentioned create table with specific binary digits,

SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

Please someone clarify me, why the MySQL supported data type is showing error while creating the table.

Comment: You appear to be using oracle

Comment: Now I'm able to create the column using 'LONG RAW' instead of BINARY.. But, please tell me how to insert a decimal value say '-5' in the 1st column and store the binary equivalent of it in the second column.. I tried using CAST function but, it's not working..                                                   insert into temp_pos_bitmap values ('-1020346790576999', cast('-1020346790576999' as LONG RAW));

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this (notice *NUMERIC* instead of *NUMBER*):

```
CREATE TABLE temp_pos_bitmap(privilege_bitmap NUMERIC,　dec_bin BINARY);
```

The error message appears to be related to the wrong datatype of the first column

Comment: I face problem while creating the second column only.. I'm able to create table with datatype NUMBER. I could create the below table,
 CREATE TABLE temp_pos_bitmap(privilege_bitmap NUMBER)

Comment: What does select version() show? It's not the case at least on 5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 and 10.1.14-MariaDB

Comment: Are you sure you're actually using mysql? ) ORA-XXYYY codes look suspicious

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the [Numeric data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html) `INTEGER`, `INT`, `SMALLINT`, `TINYINT`, `MEDIUMINT`, `BIGINT`

**Examples:**

`CREATE TABLE temp_pos_bitmap(privilege_bitmap INTEGER,　dec_bin BINARY);`

```
CREATE TABLE temp_pos_bitmap(privilege_bitmap INTEGER,　dec_bin BINARY(64));
```